# How to validate if object is of type XML

Tags: xml, r

How could I validate if object is a node of a xml object, I mean how could I check if `list[[1]]` is of type xml node.

```
txt = "<data>
       <elements>
         <elem id=\"a\" name=\"abc\"/>
         <elem id=\"a\" name=\"abc\"/>
       </elements>
       </data>"

tree <- xmlTreeParse(txt, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
list <- xpathSApply(tree, "//elements")
```

Comment: Do you need something more than class(list[[1]])?

Comment: I am not sure, this returns sometimes differnt character vectors one of them is `[1] "XMLInternalElementNode" "XMLInternalNode" "XMLAbstractNode"`

Comment: This clearly needs to be linked to the alltime best SO answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454